# Why is it that pikachu hates evolving?

Tags: pokemon

I do get it that Pikachu is iconic to the show and so changing it's form would make it less iconic, but let's just say the Pokémon world was actually real would that change Pikachu's resolve to not wanting to evolve, In my opinion Pikachu would still deny evolution and ash wouldn't force evolution onto any of his Pokémon anyway.